# Open-source or free HTTPS proxy that allows a SOCKS upstream/parent proxy?

Tags: windows, proxy

I use SSH to create a local SOCKS proxy. This works fine for Firefox, but unfortunately Postman and Git cannot use a SOCKS proxy, they support only HTTP or HTTPS proxy.

I already use [polipo](https://www.irif.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) for the HTTP proxy (it supports a parent SOCKS proxy), but it doesn't support HTTPS. What I need is something like polipo, but with HTTPS support, and it should run on Windows.

I saw mitmproxy mentioned but not sure if it supports an upstream SOCKS proxy.

Requirements: HTTPS support, support for proxy forwarding to SOCKS5 proxy, runs on Windows.

Comment: Did you look at `tsocks`, a "Transparent SOCKS Proxying Library"?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Sorry, I had forgotten about this question. In the end it turned out that polipo does support https as well, so I'm using that.